# Syntax error when I run the following code with while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I get syntax error when i run the following code with while loop. What may be the possible reason? Thanks.

```
original_balance = float(input("Enter the outstanding balance on your credit card: "))
annual_interest_rate=float(input("Enter the annual credit card interest rate as a decimal: "))
Min_monthly_payment_rate=float(input("Enter the minimum monthly payment rate as a decimal: "))

a=1

while a < 12


    Min_monthly_pay=(Min_monthly_payment_rate*original_balance)

    Interest_paid=(annual_interest_rate/12*original_balance)

    Principal_paid=(Min_monthly_pay-Interest_paid)

    original_balance=original_balance-Principal_paid

    print(original_balance)

    a=a+1
```

Comment: I was using python

Answer (score 0):

You need a `:` (colon) right after the while statement.

```
while a < 12:
```